# What should my json look like? Sending messages with web sockets

Tags: c#, json, websocket

- I have two console apps - a web socket server and a client.
- The client console app has a 'Light' property with the states on or off / true or false

Process:

1. The client sends a message to the server, requesting 'Light' be
   turned on.
2. The server then responds with a message, with the decided state (on or off)
3. The client receives the response and sets the state of the light

**I want to send the messages in JSON. This is what I came up with, is it correct?**

client to server (request):

```
"data":
{
   "type":"request"
}
```

server to client (response):

```
"data":
{
   "type":"light",
   "state":true
}
```

e.g. client handling response:

```
Data data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(message);

switch(data.Type)
{
   case "light":
      this.Light = data.State;
   break;
}
```

Does the logic and the way I am handling everything make sense?

Is the way I am using json for this sensible? Instead of me just sending plain text messages like "can you turn my light on"?

Comment: You are just missing curly braces around your message strings.

Comment: @Daredevil so like - { "data"... }? If yes, why? :O And does the logic and the way I am handling everything make sense?

Comment: if you need to ask why, then please go and take a JSON tutorial and study the syntax and structure. But...short answer: it's because everything in JSON must be wrapped in either an object or an array. You can't start a piece of JSON with a property name - what's it a property of? Nothing. It must be a property of something. So you can either go with `{ "type": "light", "state": true }` or `{ "data": { "type": "light", "state": true } }`. The second is more verbose and it's questionable if it really adds any value.

Comment: @t3ch3 You can see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Comment: BTW you can validate any JSON you write at https://jsonlint.com/, but you shouldn't be writing JSON by hand anyway. Always serialise a C# object, and then deserialise it again at the other end. That way C# will take care of making sure the JSON is valid. All you have to do is make sure your object structures map enough so that all the necessary properties get serialised and de-serialised correctly.

Comment: @ADyson I see, thank you. Lastly, is the way I am using json for this make sense? Instead of me just sending plain text messages like "can you turn my light on"?

Comment: @ADyson Yup, I am serializing and deserializing, thanks :)

Comment: I'd say using a structured format such as JSON or XML is much better than sending arbitrary strings. There are known, tested and reliable ways to serialise and deserialise data, and you can transmit complex objects containing many properties very easily, and also validate them very easily. If you make up some other text-based structure you have to provide yourself all of that functionality again from scratch (or you have to write a machine learning algorithm to try and understand an arbitrary instruction! :-) ). These schemes exist for a reason, I would use them to your advantage.

Comment: @ADyson and Daredevil, thanks guys! Not sure how I can accept your comments as answers...

Comment: I can write it all up into a proper answer, give me a minute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"data":
{
   "type":"light",
   "state":true
}
```

is not valid JSON. Everything in JSON must be wrapped in either an object or an array. You can't start a piece of JSON with a property name - what's it a property of? Nothing. It must be a property of something. So you can either go with

```
{ "type": "light", "state": true }
```

or

```
{ "data": { "type": "light", "state": true } }.
```

The second is more verbose and it's questionable if it really adds any value.

You can validate any JSON you write at sites such as https://jsonlint.com, but you shouldn't be writing JSON by hand anyway. Always serialise a C# object, and then deserialise it again at the other end. That way C# will take care of making sure the JSON is valid. All you have to do is make sure your object structures map enough so that all the necessary properties get serialised and de-serialised correctly.

Using a structured format such as JSON or XML is much better than sending arbitrary strings. There are known, tested and reliable ways to serialise and deserialise data, and you can transmit complex objects containing many properties very easily, and also validate them very easily. If you make up some other text-based structure you have to provide yourself all of that functionality again from scratch (or you have to write a machine learning algorithm to try and understand an arbitrary instruction! :-) ). These schemes exist for a reason, I would use them to your advantage.